# sudo and wifi fail simultaneously

Tags: 16.04, wireless, sudo

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Asus (7,7 GiB memory, Intel processor 5Y10 CPU @0.80Ghzx4, Intel HD graphics 5300 (broadwell Gt2), 64-bit, 117.5 GB).

After 5-15 min usage the wifi shuts down but also the ability to use any `sudo` command in the terminal. After a restart it usually works again, but sometimes 2 restarts are required before I can enjoy ubuntu for 5-15 min again.

First I thought it was just a wifi problem, but seems to be more related to a loss of administrative privileges?

Have been troubleshooting for 2 days and even re-installed once.

Any ideas?

Output of `tail -n20 /var/log/syslog`

```
Sep 17 22:07:09 ramhak-UX305FA kernel: [ 1784.092876] asus_wmi: Unknown key cf pressed
Sep 17 22:07:09 ramhak-UX305FA kernel: [ 1784.580230] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
Sep 17 22:07:35 ramhak-UX305FA AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
Sep 17 22:07:35 ramhak-UX305FA AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
Sep 17 22:07:35 ramhak-UX305FA org.freedesktop.PackageKit[823]: 22:07:35 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting due to inactivity
Sep 17 22:07:35 ramhak-UX305FA org.freedesktop.PackageKit[823]: 22:07:35 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting was requested
Sep 17 22:17:01 ramhak-UX305FA CRON[3318]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (gvfsd:1230): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Timeout was reached
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: message repeated 5 times: [ ** (gvfsd:1230): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Timeout was reached]
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (process:2816): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (process:2814): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (process:2818): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (process:2829): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (process:2831): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (gvfsd:1230): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Timeout was reached
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (process:2837): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: ** (gvfsd:1230): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Timeout was reached
Sep 17 22:19:14 ramhak-UX305FA org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1153]: message repeated 4 times: [ ** (gvfsd:1230): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Timeout was reached]
Sep 17 22:27:12 ramhak-UX305FA kernel: [ 2987.465543] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
Sep 17 22:37:32 ramhak-UX305FA org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5[1153]: ** (evolution-source-registry:1409): WARNING **: secret_service_search_sync: must specify at least one attribute to match
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use a sudo command? Are there errors? How about `tail -n20 /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: it returns nothing, the marker jumps to the next row and just stays there. I have to close down the terminal, since I am not able to do anything else. not really sure about what to look for in the syslog.. new to linux..

Comment: You can post the output of the syslog thing to http://pastebin.com, and we'll look for you.

Comment: Now I have uploaded the output to pastebin.com, if I got it right (never used it before)

Comment: Hm..., and where is the link?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wmZzhrRi

Comment: Well, some samba related error there, but nothing about wifi and sudo. Was that before or after they failed?

Comment: It failed in the time interval captured by the syslog-output... additionally it takes ages to shut down or reboot (like 10 min). Might it be power related? Also consumes tons of battery in "sleep" mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Looked carefully at the `/var/log/syslog` (thanks to mikewhatever) and figured out that the kernel might not be the most suitable one (`--end trace---` error).

Switched from a 4.10 release to a 4.4 release instead and it's working perfectly now, this solved all the issues mentioned above.